# How to make a list with a for in Dart

Tags: list, flutter, for-loop, dart

This is my first question so I'm sorry if it's not well formatted.

So, I have this object called book with the property "rating," which is an int of the number of stars. My idea is to show in a row said rating as icons and I thought I'd do it with a spread operator and a for.

I don't know if it's possible because I don't find any documentation about it or if the syntax is wrong because it expects and identifier and a ')' [See issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MupXV.png). I would appreciate help with this.

```
child: Row(
   children: [...(for (var i = 0; i < book.rating; i++) => Icon(Icons.star))],
),
```

Comment: You may be able to circumvent this issue by supplying the rating variable to this package, it just takes the integer and renders the appropriate amount of stars (including fractions of a star).  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rating_bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are syntax errors. Remove `=>`, `()` from start, `...`:

```dart
child: Row(
   children: [for (var i = 0; i < book.rating; i++) Icon(Icons.star)],
),
```

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know you could jump the => in this case! And I also hadn't thought that I didn't need the spread operator because the for would already give me separate widgets. This was very helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also made by using [List generate](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/List/List.generate.html).

```
Row(
      children: List<Widget>.generate(book.rating, (idx) => Icon(Icons.star)),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me this alternate solution!!